# How to remove a DLL, aka "maximal number of DLLs reached..."

Tags: r, seurat

Whenever I try to load a library like:

```
library(Seurat)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/mnt/data1/bin/R/NewR/R-3.4.3/library/RcppRoll/libs/RcppRoll.so':
  `maximal number of DLLs reached...
```

I'm using a server that I don't have admin privileges on, so increasing the maximal number of DLLs is not an option.

How do I remove DLLs I don't need?

I tried:

```
R.utils::gcDLLs()
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in R version > 3.5

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2375#issuecomment-399136011